# How to implement unity gain buffer with long-tailed pair?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, differential-amplifier

I read that a unity gain buffer can be implemented with an op-amp like in this circuit:[image: From UC Berkeley EE16A section 19.7 Note 19]

I also read that a long-tailed pair as an op-amp (this might be the wrong part). So according to the buffer circuit above, I believe the circuit using long-tailed pair will be like this (**edited**: this is **my own idea only** of how the long-tailed pair can be turned into a unity gain buffer which I hope to be confirmed or corrected):

[image]

However, the problem is that this configuration implies that the non-inverting input terminal will always remains at ground (0V) while the inverting input will be at G*Vin (G: gain). Hence I can't understand how negative feedback is implemented in this case since the Vout is supposed to be G(Vin - Vout).
Please correct me if there are any mistakes and demonstrate how long-tailed pair can be used as unity gain buffer (and explained with circuit schematic will be very appreciated).

Comment: The connections in your circuit are wrong. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier#Long-tailed_pair.

Comment: The second picture (and the name "long-tailed pair") are probably from a very old book. Opamps use active load and multiple gain stages for higher gain. If you have G*Vin gain, than even a small signal will achieve a big feedback signal, which counteract the change. If the non-inverting terminal voltage rises, the inverting terminal follows it through the output of the amp. Vout = G*(Vin-Vout) ==> Vout = Vin *G/(G+1). It seems correct to me.

Comment: The second picture is indeed strange. This circuit has a differential output, while the first picture has a single ended one. Q2 is also shorted and thus it is not functional.

Comment: @CL. Can you point out how is it wrong because I actually took the long-tailed pair image from the wikipedia link and added what I think is necessary to turn it into a unity gain buffer

Comment: @HorrorVacui do you mean that the long-tailed pair is not equivalent to an op-amp? about the second circuit it is actually single-ended like the first (only the non-inverting input left). Q2 is actually not shorted but the 2 terminals of Vout are connected to the two terminal of Vin- (inverting input terminal)

Comment: @DivineMK A long tailed pair is just one type of input stage to an opamp. It's main purpose is to remove the common mode while still being able to pass DC. Providing gain is secondary. After that are single ended gain stages and finally an output stage. Look up the internal schematic of an opamp like the LM358.

Comment: An opamp has a single output. You have connected both outputs of the long-tailed pair, and made a connection to the emitter of Q2 that is not an I/O.

Comment: @CL. This is actually what bothers me. Can you explain how can output have only 1 terminal? AFAIK, I/O should have 2 terminals each and maybe 1 of those are connected to ground so it is equivalent to having 1 terminal. The reason why I think the terminals of output should be connect to Q2 is that in the op-amp circuit (the first circuit), the output is connected back to the non-inverting input which I believe is Q2. Please correct me.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am aware that real op-amps have different functions and thus more complex circuit schematics but I want to explore here how can a long-tailed pair (acting as a differential amplifier) be turned into a unity gain buffer. Do you mean that this can't be achieved?

Comment: You need a single connection from the single-ended output to the inverting input. Read the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: @CL. Can you demonstrate with a circuit schematic? Because I believe single-ended I/O are actually I/O with 1 terminal grounded.

Comment: @DivineMK Without gain stages the gain may not be high enough to use ideal opamp negative feedback rules. And if you have gain stages you need an output stage since gain stages are single-ended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The long tailed pair is a pretty rubbish differential amplifier, but what you propose should work. Your problem is you've wired it up wrong. Why did you short Q2's collector to emitter?

Here's my attempt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTb5JC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All I did was connect the output to the inverting input, just like a voltage follower. It does what you would expect, except with terribly high output impedance, and awful linearity, due to low open loop gain. Here's the output, with a sinusoidal input:

[image]

To be honest, I was surprised how well it worked.

I wasn't sure it was truly working as a voltage follower (maybe this is just a really complex emitter follower, with a saturated Q2, or something), so I plugged in a couple of resistors, for 50% negative feedback, to get a gain of two:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUq4G.png)</sup>

Here are the input and output, in a simulation:

[image]

Again, surprisingly good, considering it's so primitive. I love the hilariously large input offset voltage, so clearly visible here, but well done little long-tailed pair, good job.

Comment: Where is that input offset coming from? Unmatched input impedance because there is no buffer?

Comment: @DKNguyen that sounds like a good reason. Input bias currents will be very different, because one input is sourced from 0Ω, and the other source comes via R3, R4 and R5. I'm sure there are other reasons, perhaps terrible common mode rejection. I admit, I haven't played much with LTPs in 30 years!

Comment: @SimonFitch can you further explain to me how your circuit is equivalent to the unity gain buffer circuit in my answer below? I need to add an image so I have to create an answer.

Comment: @DivineMK Ah, homework. Well, in for a penny in for a pound. Your LTP circuit is correct, so refer to that. Ignore the Vout(-) node, because a typical op-amp only has only one, single ended, output. It's the one that goes up when the non-inverting input goes up, and that's your overall output. In the op-amp follower circuit, input is to the non-inverting input, so that's where I applied the sinusoidal test signal. Lastly, the output is fed back to the inverting input. That's all I did, connect those two nodes together, just like in the op-amp version. Look closer, you'll see it.

Comment: @DivineMK Vout(-) can be ignored, because it's just an inverted version of Vout(+). When Vout(+) rises, Vout(-) falls by the same (or similar amount). You can still say that Vout(+) is equal to some large gain multiplied by the difference between Vin(+) and Vin(-). You could also say that Vout(-) is equal to some large *negative* gain multiplied by that same difference.

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you for your insights on how "double-ended" can be turned into single-ended! However, through your circuit, I cannot see how Vin can affect Vout as they are on different branches. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @DKNguyen why are you telling me? Tell OP, it's his question

Comment: @DivineMK In a nutshell, the emitter resistor is a current sink, *shared by both branches*. Any changes to current in one branch (via that resistor) must necessarily result in a change in the other, to keep Mr. Kirchhoff happy (I'm referring to Kirchhoff's Current Law). That's why changes in Vin on the left branch can influence Vout on the right. That's such a hand-wavy explanation, I feel dirty.

Comment: @SimonFitch Sorry wrong, @

Comment: @DivineMK"*different branches*" Current steering which is fundamental to how a long-tailed pair works. Replace R1 with a current source as is done in silicon. R1 is a resistance much larger than R2 or R3 to approximate a current source since the voltage across it changes little as the voltage across the other components fluctuate. If R1 was infinite Ohns, the voltage across it and thus current through it would not change at all as Vce or V_R2 or V_R3 V changed

Comment: @SimonFitch Do you mean that the current through R1 should remain constant?

Comment: @DivineMK Ideally, yes, which is why you almost always see a constant current sink there in real-life opamps.

Comment: I think the "input offset" is more of an increase in output impedance at higher voltages.  It's visible in the unity gain case (mainly because you run that one up to 10V), but becomes more pronounced when you load the output.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Good point, I did not notice there was a second schematic.

Comment: @DivineMK - Hi, You commented earlier: "*I need to add an image so I have to create an answer.*" FYI not true. In fact an OP *must not* add new information as an answer here on SE. It breaks the whole Q&A approach and may cause future problems for you, when such non-answers get deleted. For those rare cases where a comment needs an image, the technique explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) should be used. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image. If you need more help with this, please ask on our [meta]. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you very much for your guide! It is the solution I am looking for!

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you for your clear explanation! However, as you mentioned that it was a hand-wavy explanation, can you provide me with a link or textbook that have further analyses? I come across the Art of Electronics by Paul Horowitz and Windfield Hill but I hope there are other low-level explanation that begins from the very basics. I will be very grateful for that!

Comment: @DivineMK Sorry to say, I don't have any better resource on my shelf than Horowitz and Hill, and internet resources covering the topic are equally technical. I believe that any attempt to simplify by avoiding concepts like transconductance, small-signal behaviour, and wotnot, are inadequate. In short, if you want to grok this, you must first master KCL and KVL, then the BJT and its models. I've had a couple of heated debates with giants on this very forum about the LTP, and I don't want another.

Comment: @SimonFitch Thank you for reminding me that only technical explanation make real engineers!